# imagemagick convert: changing color profile

Tags: png, color-profile, imagemagick

I use the [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) `convert` command to create thumbnails for the web from large images.

```
convert y2.psd[0] -resize '80x40' y2.png
```

Some images uploaded by a customer are CMYK Photoshop files with very large custom icc profiles. A 3Mbyte photoshop file turned into a 1.2Mbyte png file, even though the output png size was 80x40. The rest of the png file seems to have been profile information. When I run

```
convert y2.png -strip y2stripped.png
```

the file size goes down from 1.2Mbytes to 2kbytes.

I'm not too worried about including any profile information with the thumbnail, but I would like to know that the png has been properly produced and does reasonably represent the original image. I can't find any information on telling `convert` what color profile to use for the output image. **Is color profile handling in `convert` well defined, please? How do I ask it to produce output with a specific color profile?**

Comment: Thanks! That's a better explanation of the `-profile` and `+profile` options. However, it doesn't explain what imagemagick does with the profile. I can add or subtract profiles from the image file. But does that change the numbers stored for the color values of the pixels in the file? That's still not clear.

Comment: Re: see [`-profile`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#profile). Maybe comparing before/after with `identify -verbose` shows something? You can also [list](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/41905/29318) the values for the colors in a palette; I just don't know if that's useful as I don't have any understanding of color profiles. If you figure it out, don't hesitate to provide an answer! Thanks!